# Report vertical layout

Tags: crystal-reports

I have existing report w/ "groups" for Total/Directs/Warehouse/Credits that span horizontally. I need to now stack these groupings vertically. What is the best way to do this in CR? I am used to SSRS, Excel, PowerBI, etc. Crystal Reports is much less intuitive than those tools.

Do I need some kind of funky nested groups? Sub reports? How should we approach this? We assumed it would be a pretty simple formatting/layout change. But it looks like it's actually quite complex to do this.

Original:

[image]

How it needs to be re-worked:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entire table you're showing is in a Footer, you can just add 3 new footer sections and duplicate the table in each (removing any columns you don't need.) Just right click the relevant section and *Insert Section Below*.

---

Otherwise you'll need to use subreports. But since you have the columns already configured, all you really have to do is:

- Save 4 subreports, *Total*, *Directs*, *Warehouse*, and *Credits*. (Just save a copy of your existing report, and delete everything that doesn't need to show up in *Total.* Rinse and repeat.)
- Import each and add the parameters as subreport links
- Give them each their own section

Comment: Thanks for this. I am running into an issue on your second bullet point; "Import each and add the parameters as subreport links"

I have the main report and subreports setup. I've added the subreports in the main report. Sales Rep and Customer parameters link easily because they are just single field with direct value mapping. But for the life of me I cannot get the Date Range parameter to pass to the sub reports.

I'm looking for info online for how to pass Date Range, but everything I see is confusing or does not work. Any chance you can clear this part up for me?

Comment: @MrB I don't know how you have the date range parameter set up, but am I correct in assuming you can boil it down to a Start Date and an End Date? If so, you could pass those two values as two separate params - then do the calculation inside the subreport.

Comment: The date field is called "Doc_Date". The date parameter is a range. When I edit links for sub report, the parameter for Report Date Range is not listed like it is for customer and sales person. It won't allow me to select Report Date Range param in sub report. It just wants to create a new param in sub report named "Pm-OINV.DocDate"

Comment: In the main report, when you go to Edit this `Doc_Date` parameter, what value shows up in the Type dropdown?

Comment: I did try adding StartDate and EndDate params in parent report. They are formula fields. But when linking params in subreport links, they do not show up as options to select

Comment: it has a Date type

Comment: @MrB It's difficult to diagnose this without seeing it in front of me, but if I were you I'd make some new Formulas to extract the start and end dates, then pass and use those instead.

Comment: I think i finally got params passing. But now issue is that, I have all of the sub reports in "Report Footer a". When I print preview,  they dont show up. Even if i just put some text box in report footer a, when I run the report, the text box doesnt show up

Comment: I got them to show up by moving them to Report Footer B.  But they dont show data so I guess params arent working. I am not loving Crystal Reports lol this feels like I'm n the early 90's. Thank you for your help getting me this far. I will keep tinkering w/ params till hopefully they work

Comment: Last update... finally got it working. It turned out the params were working, and the subreport looked blank because new page break was set on the report header of subreport. After unchecking that it seems to work perfect! Thanks 4444!!!

Comment: done. This was a humbling experience. Crystal isn't so bad but I had to unlearn a lot of assumptions that I'm used to from other tools. Using the original report as a template to generate sub reports really did get me started down the right path. Thanks!